# Delete query not working in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE name='@Name'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtproject_name.Text);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Bind();

        MessageBox.Show("deleted......");
        con.Close();
        }
```

This is my code for deleting the data from a database on a button click...but it is not deleting anything..can anyone help me with the code

Comment: Is your `WHERE` clause correct?  I.e., are there any rows in the table that match `txtproject_name.Text`?

Comment: Another thought - try `DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE name=@Name` for your SQL.  In other words, remove the single quotes - I believe `AddWithValue` will put them in for you.

Comment: yes ..there is a record

Comment: Put your exception .....

Comment: is my syntax correct??

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using `"@Name"` in AddWithValue but just `"Name"` (This is a guess).

Comment: @SSpoke, no, the @ is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Remove quotes around parameter:

```
"DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE name=@Name"
```

Comment: @user3181292 yep, you should use just parameter name. Value of appropriate type (nvarchar, int, etc) will be passed to database and parameter will be replaced with constant value of appropriate type. E.g. if you are passing string `"Bob"`, then @Name will have value `'Bob'`

Comment: i have one more problem could you please help me out/?

Comment: @user3181292 if that problem is not related to current question, then it probably better to start another question (that might help other people who will have same problem in future)

Comment: @user3181292 if you are using parameter names without any quotes, then you have another problem, and I suggest you to ask new question for that, somebody will answer you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE name=@Name", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtproject_name.Text);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Bind();

        MessageBox.Show("deleted......");
        con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the 2 ['] around @Name